# Flash.now each issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use flash.now with a Rails 4 Application.

Here's my code:

```
<% flash.now.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
     <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I get an error because of the each method: `undefined method each for #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashNow:0x00000103726c90>`

How else can I write my code without triggering the each error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `now` from `flash`:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
     <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: now I get a `undefined method any? for #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashNow:0x000001032a8ee8>` error

Comment: Also you should use it without `now`

Comment: But using it without the `now` persists, but I only want it to stay for the current action.

Comment: [It's not possible](https://www.google.ru/search?q="flash.now.each"). You should reload all flash block it you want to show flashes without reloading.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "reload all flash block"?

Comment: Create a partial and put flash block there. Then render template like `js.erb` where you can puts js code with reloading method. It calls unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: Why does it have to be javascript? Sorry, I think maybe I did a bad job explaining my question. Right now I have the code like your answer's code. But the problem is that notices seem to stick around for too long, for example if I login from the mysite.com/sign_in, I get redirected to my homepage (which doesn't have print any flash messages. But then if I click to my user/settings page, I get a flash message like: "Signed in successfully"

Comment: I think you should create another question for this. I'm not sure, but if you want to immediately show flashes, you should create them with `flash.now`, but iteration is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to find working solution( for me ;)
Using bootstrap 3 and HAML:

```
 - flash.each do |name, msg|
   %div{class: "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}"}
     %span.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert"} ×
     = msg
```

I think in ERB it will be:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
    <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span>
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```